# Query all wordpress post titles

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am using Wordpress auto suggests using [this snippet](http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/enable-auto-complete-search-in-wordpress-blog) of code

and currently it is searching all tags, I want it to search only post titles. Any help is appreciated.

This is  sql query calling all the tags which needs to be modified for all posts.

```
 <?php global $wpdb;
 $search_tags = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name from wp_terms WHERE name LIKE '$search%'");
 foreach ($search_tags as $mytag)
   {
     echo $mytag->name. " "; 
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

These days i had to do some request in a wordpress theme.
In your case ( getting title can be done easier than getting tags, as in your example link ) the stuff can be done easier (i guess).

Firstly you have to make a php page to get posts. As you maybe know you won't be able to use wp stuff in standalone php files, so your file ( let call it **get_posts.php** ) will look like

```
<?php
  // Include the file above for being able to use php stuff
  // In my case this file was in a folder inside my theme ( my_theme/custom_stuff/get_posts.php ).
  // According to this file position you can modify below path to achieve wp-blog-header.php from wp root folder
  include( '../../../../wp-blog-header.php' ); 

  // Get all published posts. 
  $list_posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );

  // Get "q" parameter from plugin
  $typing = strtolower( $_GET["q"] );

  //Save all titles
  $list_titles = array();
  foreach( $list_posts as $post ) { $list_titles[] = $post->post_title; }

  // To see more about this part check search.php from example
  foreach( $list_titles as $title ) {
    if( strpos( strtolower( $title ), $typing ) ){
      echo $title;
    }
  }

?>
```

I added some comments trying to help you better.

Now stuff get easy, you only have to call your page through jQuery plugin like

```
$('#yourInput').autocomplete( "path_to/get_posts.php" );
```

Comment: This does not answer the question really and is possibly very performance heavy since it does search after loading ALL data - for more info checkout my answer here on this page ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425438/1835470 )

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use wordpress in-build feature to get all post titles

```
// The Query
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks @GBD much appreciated but I modified the query to achieve what I wanted. Hope this could help others as well.<br />
<br />
`code`<?php global $wpdb; 
$search_tags = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title from wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '$search%'"); 
foreach ($search_tags as $mytag)
{ echo $mytag->post_title. " "; } ?>`code`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here answer your real question:

## How to query JUST post titles

### The "raw SQL" way:

Few important things:

- **escape search for SQL!** (also do that for the tags search!) use `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->esc_like()`
- if you only need 1 column, you can use `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_col()`
  `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results()` is if you want to fetch more columns in one row
- use `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->tableBaseName` to make your code portable - takes care of the **prefix**
  e.g. `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts`
- When querying posts you must also think about which **post_type** and **post_status** you want to query
  => usually the `post_status` you want is`publish`, but `post_type` may vary based on what you want
- WordPress table "posts" contains ALL post types - post, page, custom, **but also navigation, contact forms etc. could be there!** => I strongly advice to use explicit `post_type` condition(s) in WHERE ! :)

...`$GLOBALS` is same as globalizing variabl -today performance difference is little

```
<?php
  // to get ALL published post titles of ALL post types (posts, pages, custom post types, ...
  $search_post_titles = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_col(
    "SELECT post_title from {$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts}
     WHERE (
       (post_status = 'publish')
       AND
       (post_title LIKE '{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->esc_like($search)}%') 
     )
     ORDER BY post_title ASC
  "); // I also added ordering by title (ascending)
  // to only get post titles of Posts(Blog)
  // you would add this to conditions inside the WHERE()
  // AND (post_type = 'post')
  // for Posts&Pages
  // AND ((post_type = 'post') OR (post_type = 'page'))

  // test output:
  foreach ($search_post_titles as $my_title) {
   echo $my_title . " "; 
  }

?>
```

### The WP_Query way

This is more wordpress but has a little overhead, because although there is a `fields` param for `new WP_Query()`/`get_posts()`, it only has options:

'all' - all fields (also default), 'ids' - just ids, 'id=>parent' - ... if you pass anything else, *you still get all*, so you still need to add "all" **BUT** - WP however has filters for altering fields in SELECT.

I tried to make it the same as the raw SQL version, **but it depends on how does WP does it's "search"** - which I think is `%search%` for 1 word + some more logic if there are more words. You could **leverage the `$clauses` filter used for `fields` to also add your custom where *INSTEAD* of adding the `'s'` into `$args`** (remember to append to not-lose existing WHEREs `$clauses['where' .= "AND ...;`). Also `post_type => 'any'` *does not produce always the same results as the raw query in cases like Navigation, Contact forms etc...*

Also WP_Query sanitizes the input variables so actually don't escape `$args`!

```
<?php
  $args = [
      'fields' => 'all', // must give all here and filter SELECT(fields) clause later! 
      'posts_per_page'   => -1, // -1 == get all
      'post_status'      => 'publish',
      's'                => $search,
      // I also added ordering by title (ascending):
      'orderby'          => 'title',
      'order'            => 'ASC',
      'post_type'        => 'any', // all "normal" post types
      // 'post_type'     => 'post', // only "blog" Posts
      // 'post_type'     => ['post', 'page'], // only blog Posts & Pages   
  ];

  $onlyTitlesFilter = function($clauses, $query) {
        // "fields" overrides the column list after "SELECT" in query
        $clauses['fields'] = "{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts}.post_title";

        return $clauses; // !FILTER! MUST RETURN!
  };
  $onlyTitlesFilterPriority = 999;

  // add filter only for this query
  add_filter('posts_clauses', $onlyTitlesFilter, $onlyTitlesFilterPriority, 2);
  // Pro-tip: don't use variable names like $post, $posts - they conflict with WP globals!
  $my_posts = (new WP_Query($args))->get_posts();

  // !IMPORTANT!
  // !remove the filter right after so we don't affect other queries!
  remove_filter('posts_clauses', $onlyTitlesFilter, $onlyTitlesFilterPriority);

  // test output:
  // note that I used "my"_post NOT just $post (that's a global!)
  foreach($my_posts as $my_post) {
    echo $my_post->post_title . " ";
  }

?>
```

Don't be confused - you will still get the array of `WP_Posts` - WP will throw some default properties&values into it, but in reality it will only query and fill-in with real values the fields you specify in the filter.

PS: I've tested these - they are working codes (at least on WP 5.4 and PHP7 :) )